# Is $y=x^2$ smooth at origin?

Tags: conic-sections

if $r(t)=t^2 i + t^4 j$, then it is a parabola $y = x^2$. It satisfies the condition of non smooth curve i.e. $\frac{dr}{dt}=0$ at $t=0$. But geometrically it shows the curve (parabola) is smooth at $(0,0)$. Why is this so?

Comment: It is only  an *arc* of parabola.

Comment: @Bernard What's the difference?

Comment: It depends on the parametrization you have: Take for example $(t,t^2)$ and $(t^2,t^4)$ and calculate the derivative. It is $(1,2t)$ and $(2t,4t^3)$. The first is never equal to zero, but the second...

Comment: That explains why $\mathrm dr/\mathrm dt=0$.

Comment: To expand @Bernard's comment it is only the right half of the parabola since $t^2$ is always positive.

Answer (score 3):

A curve is non-smooth at a point if *every* parametrisation is either not differentiable or has $\frac{dr}{dt} = 0$ at that point. It's not enough that you have found *one* such parametrisation.

There are other parametisations of the same curve, such as $r(t) = ti + t^2j$, which does have a well-defined, non-zero derivative everywhere, showing that the curve is smooth.